# App Store Connect: What happens when you click Remove From Sale?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

If I've pushed a build to App Store Connect and it's approved, and I click `Remove From Sale`, will it affect users that haven't downloaded it yet?

Answer (score 0):

When you remove this app, it will no longer be available on the App Store.

[image]

*Q: will it affect users that haven't downloaded it yet?*

A: Yes, You app will not show on App Store.